# Resolve Google Sheet treating plain text values with leading zero as duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using `=countif(F:F,F1)>1` as a conditional formatting to indicate duplicates for the Column F. Unfortunately it displays e.g. the values **2000** and **02000** as duplicates as well.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If treated like numbers, 20 and  020 are the same. Can you share the sheet you are using and more information on  it?

Comment: @Kessy Thanks for your interest. Cell values are formatted as plain text. We already got this issue resolved. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A=A1)>1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(A:A=A1)>1)*(A1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a ton! Your formula =(SUMPRODUCT(A:A=A1)>1)*(A1<>"") and the formula provided by @basic (=SUMPRODUCT(A:A=A1)>1) are very similar and both work. May I ask what the appended *(A1<>"") does in particular?

Comment: @Chiggiddi it not paints empty rows

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my case, it is not needed, as =SUMPRODUCT(A:A=A1)>1 is working just right. I would love to mark your answer as well but unfortunately I can only mark a single answer as most useful.

Comment: Would the formula =(A1<>"")*(SUMPRODUCT(A:A=A1)>1) increase performance since this would skip comparison on empty cells? Also, if the first parameter (A1<>"") = false will this skip the second parameter (SUMPRODUCT(A:A=A1)>1) as well? If so, this would also increase performance.

Comment: @Chiggiddi no, and also no